# R package for calculating the moles of a oxygen in air

Tags: r, package

Is there an r package that include a function for calculating moles of oxygen in air, given temperature, pressure, etc.

I'm looking for something like [marelac](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/marelac/index.html), but for air, not water

Comment: Can't you calculate such things manually (around STP, at least) using the [ideal gas law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law)? (more of a chemistry SE topic, I guess)

Comment: yes I can, I was just hoping someone had written something already.  The ideal gas law is a start, but doesn't correct for humidty, which changes the oxygen concentration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve PV = nRT for `n`:

```
n = PV/RT
```

Make a function:

```
moles_n <- function( press, # in SI unit pascals
                     volume, # in SI unit cubic metres
                     R_const,
                     temp  # degrees Kelvin
                     ){ 
                R_const = 8.3144598(48) # J⋅mol−1⋅K−1

                press*vol/(R_const*temp) }
```

Units and constant looked up at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant. (I can remember some physical constants but this one went back to high-school chemistry class, more than half a century ago in my case.) I suppose if one were entirely scrupulous, one would put in the correction factors for different gases. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation and http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch4/deviation5.html

I thought maybe there could be a package as you requested (although you should realize that package-request questions generally get closed.) I found two, the `CHNOSZ`-package and the `seacarb`-package,  that do indicate an effort to instantiate "thermodynamic" functions", but my perusal of the function summaries makes me think these are also primarily for aqueous solutions:

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/CHNOSZ/html/00Index.html

Eventually I found package- `IAPWS95`, which you should examine carefully:

http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/IAPWS95/html/00Index.html

The R-way for searching that I find most efficient is to use sos::findFn:

```
findFn("pressure temperature gas")
found 89 matches;  retrieving 5 pages
2 3 4 5 
Downloaded 87 links in 21 packages.
```

Comment: Thank you.  I was not aware of the sos package